# How to return every iteration of a recursive function into another function

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have written a recursive function which is based on the triangular numbers. When a number of people is passed into the function, it returns the number of possible connections between them. This works fine, but I would like to return every iteration of this function into an array - as I then plan to display this list to the screen. This new function would return an array, for example of [1,3,6,10].

I don't know whether I could do this within my pre-existing function, or whether I would need some kind of helper/secondary function. The return value which is passed back into my current function is the number of people (rather than the number of connections), so I would think I either need to add an additional parameter into this function, or write another one to operate entirely alongside it.

It seems like it should be quite simple, and I have managed to generate a console log of the values on every iteration - the issue is that I need these values to be added to another array, and for this array to only be returned when my recursive function has finished.

My code for the function is as follows:

```js
function connection(numberOfPeople) {

    if (numberOfPeople == 1) {
        return 0;
    }

    const returnVal = (connection(numberOfPeople-1) + (numberOfPeople-1));
    console.log(returnVal);

    return returnVal;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> ...so I would think I either need to add an additional parameter into this function...

Exactly! Like this (see the indicated changes/additions):

```
function connection(numberOfPeople, theArray = []) {
    // -----------------------------^

    let returnVal;                // <===
    if (numberOfPeople == 1) {
        returnVal = 0;            // <=== Didn't return here so we have a common
    } else {                      //      path at the end
        returnVal = (connection(numberOfPeople-1, theArray) + (numberOfPeople-1));
    // ---------------------------------------------^
    }
    console.log(returnVal);
    theArray.push(returnVal);     // <===

    return theArray;              // <===
}
```

Note that since the result is pushed after the recursion, the array will end up with the *last* value calculated followed by the second-to-last followed by the third-to-last, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function getConnections(numberOfPeople){
  var connections =[];
  (function connection(numberOfPeople) {
    if (numberOfPeople == 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    let returnVal = connection(numberOfPeople-1) + numberOfPeople-1 ;
    connections.push(returnVal)
    return returnVal 
  })(numberOfPeople)
  return connections
}


console.log(getConnections(5))
```

> Closure is when a function "remembers" its lexical scope even when the
>   function is Executed outside that lexical scope.

The connection function  will have a reference of connections variable because of closure property of the function.

> An IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) is a JavaScript
>   function that runs as soon as it is defined. [more detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

We have used the IIFE function to execute the connection method without polluting the external scope.

Alernatively this can be done by simply calling the connection function.

```js
function getConnections(numberOfPeople){
  var connections =[];
  function connection(numberOfPeople) {
    if (numberOfPeople == 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    let returnVal = connection(numberOfPeople-1) + numberOfPeople-1 ;
    connections.push(returnVal)
    return returnVal 
  }
  connection(numberOfPeople)
  return connections
}


console.log(getConnections(5))
```

Comment: This seems to work, thank you! Could you please explain in a bit more depth how this is working, though? This seems to be an example of a closure, if I'm getting this right,

I'm particularly unsure about (numberOfPeople) in brackets right before the return connections line. Is there any chance you could explain this, please?

Comment: @matt93 I have tried to explain the code. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this - that makes sense now. So, the (numberOfPeople) line which was confusing me is an example of an IIFE?

Comment: yes, In that line we were calling the IIFE function and passing the numberOfPeople as a parameter.